# Maven version used by Netbeans 6.7.1

Tags: maven, netbeans, settings

I'm developing Maven projects using Netbeans 6.7.1.

How can I see where the Maven that my Netbeans is using is located? I'd like to edit the settings.xml file of this Maven installation.

Is there a way that I can run `mvn -version` using Netbeans? Before I downloaded Netbeans I already had a Maven 3 installation on my computer, to which MAVEN_HOME is pointing, but I think this Netbeans uses Maven 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Netbeans 6.7 installation available at the moment. But as far as I remember you could find the Maven settings in Netbeans under "Tools / Options / Miscellaneous". There should be a tab for Maven.

If you want to use your external installation you can setup your external Maven within the project properties (see this [screenshot](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices#Binding_Maven_goals_to_IDE_actions))

Comment: I found the Maven tab under Netbeans > Preferences > Miscelaneous, but this was mostly helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `mvn info` in your console

Comment: That won't help him to determine which version Netbeans is using if he has an external Maven installation.